# Using Python Functions in Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just starting to learn Python and I'm having a hard time testing things out in the terminal. 
What I want to do is simply run a pre-written Python method in the Python interpreter. (I know how to run it by doing python file_name.py, but I want to run it in the interpreter itself).

So if I for example had the file "exampleModule.py":

```
def exampleFunc(data):
    print(data)
```

Then in the terminal I run Python and do:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import exampleModule
>>> exampleFunc('Hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'exampleFunc' is not defined
```

The thing that I don't get about this is that if I run the module in the Python IDLE, I can access the exampleFunc, but not in the terminal interpreter.

Thanks!

Comment: You're running Darwin? Cool! I'd like to get it set up myself--may I contact you for pointers?

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm super honored, but that's the Unix fork OS X runs on. Sorry @FredBarclay, though I'd totally recommend Linux Mint.

Comment: Oh, so is that what OS X terminal looks like? BTW: I absolutely agree on Mint--I'm on LMDE Betsy and loving it! :)

Comment: Yep! It's a pretty useful terminal, though definitely restricted. Cool, I'll check that out the next time I make a VM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
import exampleModule
```

you have to write the full name of its functions. According to the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)*,

> This does not enter the names of the functions defined in **exampleModule**
>   directly in the current symbol table; it only enters the module name
>   **exampleModule** there. Using the module name you can access the functions

If you want to write only the function name, do

```
from exampleModule import *
```

As, according to the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)*

> This does not introduce the module name from which the imports are
>   taken in the local symbol table (so in the example, **exampleModule** is not
>   defined).

**changed the function name to yours for better understading.*

Comment: Or use the more explicit import -- `from exampleModule import exampleFunc`

Comment: Oh god that was simple (and makes total sense). Thank you so much!

Comment: I still cannot stress this enough though:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

`import *` puts a lot of things into your namespace you don't expect. It's much better to be explicit and say `from package import module` or `from module import class`.

Comment: In general, I do things like `import example_module as em` and then `em.some_func`.  With name completion, as in IDLE, typing `em.` and pausing brings up a box with a list of all names in `em`, and only names in `em`.